# Unable to get innerText in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

HTML part

```
<body>
  <div><span>Hello how are you</span></div>
  <div><span>Some random text</span></div>
  <div>This is more text</div>
</body>
```

Typescript part

```
someMethod() {
  const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  const arrayAllDivs = Array.from(allDivs);
  const allText = arrayAllDivs.map(divs => divs.innerText);
  console.log(allText);
}
```

Although I am able to log the innerText of all these divs in the console. I am getting an error:  error TS2339: *Property 'innerText' does not exist on type '{}'.* How to resolve this error as this is breaking up the build.

Comment: i think you need to use *ngFor to display those data

Comment: What about applying any: `map((divs: any) => divs.innerText);` ? (It's just an idea didn't try it)

Comment: @axi-code That worked.